# C++ syntax for custom exception class

Tags: c++, exception, custom-exceptions

I am fairly new to C++ and have found the following code snippet for a custom exception extended from std::exception. The only part I don't understand is the `: err_msg(msg) {}` after the constructor definition. Can anyone explain why this is not in the function braces?

```
class my_exception : public std::exception {
  private:
    std::string err_msg;

  public:
    my_exception(const char *msg) : err_msg(msg) {};
    ~my_exception() throw() {};
    const char *what() const throw() { return this->err_msg.c_str(); };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member `err_msg` is already initialized by the initializer list.

```
my_exception(const char *msg) : err_msg(msg) {};
//                         here ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So nothing to do for the contructor.

---

**Sidenote:** There is a some discussion about **not using std::string in exceptions**. Just google for it or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831029/not-using-stdstring-in-exceptions).