# Is returning a pointer to a local variable always undefined behavior

Tags: c++, function, pointers, local, undefined-behavior

I have read that we should not return a pointer or a reference to a local variable.  So in the below given example, i understand that when i wrote: `return f;` inside function `foo`, i am returning a pointer to a local variable. And using that pointer outside the function, will lead to undefined behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

const char* foo()
{
    const char* f = "ffdf";
    return f;//returning pointer to a local variable
}

const char* func()
{
    return "fsfs";
}

int main()
{
    const char* ptr = func();
    const char* f = foo();
    std::cout<<f<<std::endl; //I know this is undefined behavior because we're using a pointer that points to a local variable 
    std::cout<<ptr; //But IS THIS UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR too?
}
```

My question is that does the same hold true for the return statement `return "fsfs";` inside function `func`. I am aware that in C++17 there is mandatory copy elison. So my question is directed towards all modern C++ version(C++11, C++17, etc). Does the behavior depends/differs on C++ version.

In particular, i know that the statement `std::cout<<f<<std::endl;` inside `main` is always undefined behavior because we're using a pointer(dangling) that points to a local variable. But does the statement `std::cout<<ptr;` also leads to undefined behavior. If not why and what will happen here.

PS: I might be wrong in describing what is actually happening in the first `cout` statement too. So please correct me if i am wrong. Also, my original intention was not restricted to a particular type like a string literal. For example, i could've have chosen to return an `int` instead of a string literal and have the return type as `const int&`. But since people have already started answering i am not changing the example to use `int`.

Comment: afaict string literal have no lifetime.

Comment: oh and foo is also not UB, (re-read your question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872465/const-char-value-lifetime)

Comment: @nomoresegmentationfaults there OP returns a pointer to a local pointer to a string literal. This is different from the quesiton here

Comment: "i could've have chosen to return an int instead" Do you mean `int*` because returning a single `int`  is safe

Comment: @drescherjm [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71693551/is-returning-a-pointer-to-a-local-int-variable-always-undefined-behavior) is the follow up question.

Comment: You aren't returning a pointer to a local variable. You are returning the value of a local variable, which is not problematic. If you had done `return &f;` then that would be a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes i just realized that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning a pointer to a non-static function local variables will cause the pointer you get at the call site to be a dangling pointer and using it will have undefined behavior.

Here, this is not the case.  A string literal has static storage duration, meaning it will live until the end of the program.  This means it is safe to return a pointer to a string literal that was declared in a function.

So both `foo` and `func` are safe, but if you had

```
const char * bar()
{
    std::string text = "some text";
    // stuff
    return text.c_str();
}
```

Then you would be returning a pointer to an object that no longer exits and would have UB trying to read from that returned pointer.

Comment: Then how do you solve bar in your example ?

Comment: char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
return cstr;
??

Comment: @kingsjester You either do like the OP did in `foo` or `func` or you switch the function to return a `std::string`