# Return a string but get garbage

Tags: c++, string, char, return, strcpy

I'm trying to return a string from a function like this:

```
virtual const char* what() const throw()
{   
    std::string str = "Name Error: name ";
    str+= n_name;
    str += " is not defined";
    char ret[256]="";
    const char* temp = str.c_str();
    strcpy(ret, temp);
    return ret;
}
```

But when I try to print it in another place:

```
const char* str= exc.what();
std::cout << str;
```

The output is garbage.

I thought the problem was the char[] and it should be char*, but when I changed it to

```
char* ret="";
```

the program crashed at

```
strcpy(ret, temp);
```

Can someone please help me?
P.S. the function has to return a const char*

Comment: You return a pointer to invalid memory. You need to allocate some memory to which you pointer will point. See 'malloc' or 'new[]'.

Answer (score 0):

By the moment `what()` returns and the return value is stored into `str` the array `ret` will have been destroyed because of it's scope and this the pointer returned from `what()` is a dangling pointer which causes undefined bevahiour upon derefencing. You should either `new` the array (and `delete` it after using it) or just return a `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks I found a way!

Answer (score 0):

Main problem comes from returning pointer to a local variable. If you use `-Wall` compiler option (which I encourage you to use in *every* compilation you done), you will get:

> warning: address of local variable 'ret' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Indeed, `char ret[256]="";` is local to function. At the end of function, local variables don't exist anymore. So, when `std::cout << str;` is executed, pointed memory doesn't exist anymore.

When you use `char* ret="";`, you don't allocate memory. You just have a pointer which point to a read-only static memory containing `""`. And always with `-Wall` option, you will get an warning which says you are doing something wrong:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

You have to allocate memory:

```
char * ret = new char[str.size()+1];
```

But take care, each `new` have to have somewhere a `delete` => every manually allocated memory should be deallocated manually

Comment: Are you sure char ret[256]="" allocates memory? How is it different from char* ret="" which points to read-only static memory?

Comment: `char ret[256]=""` automatically allocate memory on stack for 256 `char` and initialize it to `""`. Deallocation is automatically done at the end of function

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement an exception. Why don't you just inherit from `std::runtime_error` which already provides the machinery to make this work? You just need to pass your desired message to its constructor.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error

Comment: That's the part of the task- to create exceptions. Thanks anyway

Comment: You might get better answers if you asked about your real problem. But I think you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/134612/212870