# C++ exception not handling as expected

Tags: c++, sorting, exception

I'm trying to throw an exception in my code if a vector that is created from user input is not sorted in either descending or ascending order.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
vector <int> vec;

//Let user fill a vector with 12 integers.
//cout << "Please note that input data should be either increasing or decreasing." << endl;
int n = 0;
int size = 0;
while(size < 12) {
    cout << "Type integer to add to the vector." << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vec.push_back(n);
    ++size;
}

//throw exception if unsorted
try {
    if (!((is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end())) || (is_sorted(vec.end(), vec.begin())))) {
        throw "Input was not sorted.";
    }
}
catch(exception &error){
    cerr << "Error: " << error.what() << endl;
}
```

}

I have not included the rest of the code, which searches for a particular number, because I am pretty sure that it is irrelevant to this issue.  When the data filled into the vector is ascending or descending, everything is fine, but when I test the exception, I get, "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*' Aborted" instead of my desired error message.  I don't understand what is going on here.  Is it something wrong with the way I'm handling exceptions or am I using the sort() function incorrectly?

Comment: If you swap `begin()` and `end()`, you don't get an interval that goes backwards, you get an empty interval. You want to use `rbegin()` and `rend()` instead.

Comment: There is no sense to throw and catch an exception in the same block. You should use a simple 'if' instead.

Comment: Wow, so many parentheses! You can remove the ones around the calls to `is_sorted` -- they're redundant. And you can get rid of the outermost pair in the expression inside the `if` statement by applying De Morgan's theorem: `!(A || B)` is equivalent to `!A && !B`.

Comment: @n.m. -- it's worse than that. Trying to use the sequence `[end(), begin())` produces undefined behavior because the second iterator is not reachable from the first.

Comment: @Mattia72 -- maybe, but this is **supposed to be** a minimal example **that shows the problem**. And it does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, all types are throwable and catchable, but you are only catching subclasses of `std::exception`.

The best fix to your code would be changing your throw statement to:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Input was not sorted.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing a `const char*` not an `std::exception`. So catch it as a `const char*`:

```
  catch(const char* error) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << error << "\n";
  }
```

Or throw an `std::exception`.

Remember that you *can* throw many types and have many `catch` blocks, the one that will be invoked is the one that matches the type of the thrown exception.

Comment: Minor niggle. I don't think `std::exception` has a constructor that eats a string or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch an exception, you should throw an exception, not a `const char*`.
See this answer: [c++ exception : throwing std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134569/c-exception-throwing-stdstring)